# SQL Query logic for split the budget into remaining days for a Month according to Sales

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server

I have table for Sales and Budget with Date. I need to calculate difference and New_Budget (depends on Sales and difference)

```
CREATE TABLE MasterData (
Business_Date DATE,
Sales float,
Budget float,
Difference_Budget float,
New_Budget float
);

INSERT INTO MasterData VALUES
('2023-03-01', 100, 150, 0, 0),
('2023-03-02', 200, 190, 0, 0),
('2023-03-03', 0, 180, 0, 0);
```

Table Data:

[image]

I need to calculate **Difference and New Budget** like below:

[image]

Difference Budget = (Budget - Sales)

New_Budget = Budget + Difference_Budget (Difference Budget was split into remaining days for that Month)

New Budged Example:

For Date 1 (always New_Budget = Budget)

For Date 2 (Date 1 difference 50 was divided into remaining days for that month. 50/30 = 1.67)
(So New_Budget = (190 + 1.67) = 191.67)

For Date 3 (New_Budget = (180 + 1.67 + 0.34) = 182.01).
(Calculation is 50/30 = 1.67 (Date 1) and 10/29 = 0.34 (Date 2)).

Difference Budget needs to                    split into remaining days for that Month.

I need SQL select query for C# coding purposes.

Comment: Are you wanting to calculate that in an SQL query or C# code? Only tag the technology relevant to the solution you desire.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: How do you derived the `Budget` value for `3/4/2023` , `3/5/2023` etc?

Comment: You need a lot, but you haven't demostrated what you yourself tried. This isn't a free coding service you know.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the code. You need to  use lag and sum function to achieve the results:

```
drop table if exists #a 
drop table if exists #b

CREATE TABLE #a (
Business_Date DATE,
Sales float,
Budget float
);

INSERT INTO #a VALUES
('2023-03-01', 100, 150),
('2023-03-02', 200, 190),
('2023-03-03', 0, 180)

--- Find prevous value of Difference_Budget and prev value of day of Business_Date and subtract it from total days in month
select *,(case when day(Business_Date) = 1 then 0 else lag(Difference_Budget,1) over (order by Business_Date) end )  as New_Budget_previous_day,
isnull(day(dateadd(day,-1,dateadd(month,1,DATEFROMPARTS(year(Business_Date),month(Business_Date),1)))) - day(lag(Business_Date,1) over (order by Business_Date)),0) as total_No_Days
into #b
from
(
select * , 
       abs(case when sales = 0 then 0 else budget - sales end) as Difference_Budget
       
from #a
)as a

--Calculating Running_total_remaining_days by using sum function and then adding its value to budget
select *,sum(remaining_days) over (partition by year(Business_Date),month(Business_Date) 
                                   order by Business_Date 
                                   rows between unbounded preceding and current row
                                ) as Running_total_remaining_days,

        budget + sum(remaining_days) over (partition by year(Business_Date),month(Business_Date) 
                                   order by Business_Date 
                                   rows between unbounded preceding and current row
                                ) as New_budget
from
(
select * , cast(case when total_No_Days = 0 then 0 else New_Budget_previous_day/total_No_Days end as decimal(3,2)) as remaining_days
from #b
) as a
```

[image]

Comment: Please accept the solution if you find the code helpful. Thanks